# Multiplying different number formats in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

I'm using an excel document to track my hours at work (this is my 3rd question about it)

I'm trying to figure out how to multiply a time (i.e. 62:05, which is how long I have worked for over 2 weeks), by my hourly rate (11$/hr) and get approximate gross earnings in this format:  $667.43

my time format is [hh]:mm and the 11/hr format doesn't do anything other than the total being 29.0000382 something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this formula:

```
=A1*24*B1
```

[image]

Comment: Jared was forgetting that hours are stored in Excel as a fraction of a day so this answer just multiplies the date value * 24 before multiplying by hourly rate.